# Form with radio buttons not submitted

Tags: angular5

I have a form with two radio buttons which is enabled only when a checkbox is checked.

My problem is when I check the checkbox and click the submit button, the radio value is not getting posted. But after I click on the checkbox and then click on one of the radio buttons then the value is posted.

How to fix this issue?

This is the code I have tried:

### HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="filterProductTargetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitFilterDataList(filterProductTargetForm.value)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="isProductTypeChecked" formControlName="checkProductType" (change)="onProductTypeChange($event)" />
            <label>Select A or B</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-2 uni-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10 prduct-type-radio">
            <fieldset [disabled]="!isProductTypeChecked">
                <input type="radio" [checked]="isProductTypeChecked == true" value="A" formControlName="productTypeSelected" [(ngModel)]="productTypeSelected">
                <span>B</span>

                <br>

                <input type="radio" value="B" formControlName="productTypeSelected" [(ngModel)]="productTypeSelected">
                <span>B</span>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="uni-button def" [disabled]="!filterProductTargetForm.valid">OK</button>
</form>
```

### TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filterProductTargetForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'checkProductType': '',
        'productTypeSelected': ''
    });
}

public filterProductTargetForm: FormGroup;
public isProductTypeChecked = false;

onProductTypeChange(event: any) {
    this.isProductTypeChecked = !this.isProductTypeChecked;
    if(!this.isProductTypeChecked)
        this.filterProductTargetForm.controls['productTypeSelected'].reset();
}
```

Comment: `[disabled]="!isProductTypeChecked"` disables the radios when the checkbox is checked. Disabled controls aren't considered part of the form anymore. Basides, you're mixing template-driven directoves (ngModel) with reactive form directives (formGroup, formControlName), which isn't right.

Comment: @JBNizet hmm I am working on reactive form. Can you pls help me. I need to pass radio value only when checkbox is selected

Comment: Start by reading the guide about reactive forms on angular.io. Realize that ngmodel is not used in reactive forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all `ngModel` from your template when using reactive forms.

When the checkbox value changes, in your `onProductTypeChange` function set the `productTypeSelected` value

```
this.filterProductTargetForm.controls['productTypeSelected'].setValue('A');
```

Working [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-so-54070033)

Comment: thank you but when you click checkbox and click submit radio button is not post

Comment: value is not submitted. {checkProductType: true, productTypeSelected: false}

Comment: what do you expect as a result?

Comment: in the code, there is one select box followed by 2 radio buttons. Now click on the checkbox will automatically select first radio button. Now  click on OK button without touching the radio button , see the console. value is not submitted. Now click on second radio button and click OK . check console value is passed

Comment: Now I understand, I've updated the answer and the DEMO

Comment: Great! think of [correcting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer so other users will know it been answered